# Convert int to LPCWSTR by using wsprintf

Tags: c++, api

As the following code:

```
int a = 16;
wchar_t *buffer = {0};
wsprintf(buffer,L"%d", a);

MessageBox(NULL, buffer, buffer, MB_OK);
```

I want to covert int to LPCWSTR in order to put MessageBox.
I really newbie in using wsprintf. Any one can help me explain clearly for me using this function??? (Please, I also read MSDN but still dont't clear)

I mean, I want to print "16" in MessageBox

Comment: `wsprintf` shares the same requirement that `sprintf()` does. you need a valid address to write your output upon, and you're most-certainly not supplying that with `wchar_t *buffer = {0};` And in case you weren't aware, `wsprintf()` is a Microsoft Windows'ism, not to be confused with [`swprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwprintf), the wide-char version of `sprintf()` from the standard library.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You initialize your `buffer` to `nullptr`. Just create an array of `wchar_t`s that allocates enough space for you and you're off the hook:

```
int a = 16;
wchar_t buffer[256];
wsprintfW(buffer, L"%d", a);
MessageBoxW(nullptr, buffer, buffer, MB_OK);
```

Comment: +1 for the forced wide-char versions of the windows API. (and of course the nudge concerning having a valid write-buffer).